# Non-trivial reduction form SAT to $3$-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, satisfiability, 3-sat, sat-solvers

Looking for any idea for reduction from $SAT \leq 3-SAT$ where $SAT$ is known to have $d$ variables at most in each clause. I am looking for a reduction in which the resulting formula will not depend on the value of $d$. The classical reduction adds $O(d)$ new variables per clause, so this is not good to my case.

Do such reductions even exist?

**Edit:** Even if it's impossible to find such reductions, maybe there are other interesting reductions which are not the classical one, they can also be interesting?

Comment: You can't have it not dependent on $d$. 

Consider just a single clause with $d$ different variables. After the reduction, it must have at least $\frac{d}{3}$ clauses, since each clause can "hold" only up to $3$ variables, and there are in total $d$ of them.